# Как работает оператор end(), какое именно значение он возвращает, и почему end()-- работает как-то странно,с second программа зависает?

Tags: c++

```
   map<int,string> h;
h[1]="q";
h[20]="d";
h[3]="s";
h[90]="l";
h[9]="f";

map<int,string>::iterator it;
for(it=h.begin();it!=h.end();++it)
    cout<<it->first<<"\t";
cout<<"\n"<<h.end()-- ->first;
```

Comment: Функция `end` возвращает итератор на гипотетический элемент, следующий за последним элементом контейнера. Этот итератор обозначает окончание контейнера. Его нельзя разыменовывать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `end` возвращает итератор на несуществующий элемент, следующий за последним элементом контейнера. Он нужен только для сравнения с ним текущего итератора в цикле. Разыменовывать его нельзя.

У вас ошибка в применении [оператора декремента](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec). Оператор постфиксного декремента создаёт копию операнда (в вашем случае итератора `end`), затем уменьшает исходный объект (не копию) на единицу, а затем возвращает ранее созданную копию. К копии не применялась операция уменьшения, поэтому значение, возвращённое конструкцией `h.end()--` - это тот же самый итератор `end`. К нему нельзя применять операцию разыменовывания.

Что делать? Использовать операцию префиксного декремента или функцию `std::prev`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int,string> h;
    h[1] = "q";
    h[20] = "d";
    h[3] = "s";
    h[90] = "l";
    h[9] = "f";
    
    map<int,string>::iterator it;
    for (it = h.begin(); it != h.end(); ++it)
        cout<< it->first << "\t" << it->second << endl;
    cout << (--h.end()) -> first << endl;
    cout << (--h.end()) -> second << endl;
    //cout<<"\n"<< std::prev(h.end())->first;
    //cout<<"\n"<< std::prev(h.end())->second;
    return 0;
}
```

Функция `std::prev` хороша ещё тем, что она может найти и возвратить предыдущий итератор независимо от того, может ли оператор декремента применяться к rvalue. Например, в этом коде декремент работать не будет:

```
int main()
{
    int a[100] = {0};
    //auto last = --std::end(a); //Ошибка: оператор декремента не определён для данного типа rvalue.
    auto last = std::prev(std::end(a));
    cout << *last;
    return 0;
}
```

Если же декремент для итератора не определён вообще, то функция `std::prev` не поможет. Например, возьмём итератор контейнера `std::forward_list`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::forward_list<int> list;
    list.push_front(1);
    //auto last = std::end(list);
    //--last;
    auto last = std::prev(std::end(list));
    cout << *last;
    return 0;
}
```

Некоторые компиляторы могут такое проглотить, но работать это не будет. Например, x86_64 gcc 12.2 успешно компилирует, но программа вылетает с ошибкой. А Visual Studio при компиляции выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
static_assert failed: 'prev requires bidirectional iterator'
```

Comment: *"не все итераторы имеют перегрузку операторов инкремента и декремента"* Инкремент есть у всех. Не у всех он работает на rvalue. Декремент - не у всех, но если его нет, `prev` не поможет. `prev` нужен только чтобы безопасно вызывать их на rvalue.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а можно пример, где инкремент и декремент не работают на rvalue?

Comment: Указатели - это тоже итераторы, для них не работает. И для своих классов можно навесить `&` на инкремент.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, проверил, убедился. Вы не против, если я перенесу это в ответ?

Comment: Конечно, для этого и пишу.  :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а вот такой вопрос, в листе, на пример, оператор -- это переход по указателю на предыдущий элемент, в мепе это тоже куда-то наверх, а вот как мы у элемента end() которого нет, можем вызывать этот метод, откуда несуществующий элемент знает о предыдущем? Или итераторы еще как-то хранят порядок элементов в контейнере и ++ или -- это просто двигаемся по номеру элмента?

Comment: @Sashkinzz Про мапу не уверен, можно задать отдельный вопрос. Для листа, например, можно хранить в самом объекте `list` этот "несуществующий" элемент - только указатели на предыдущий и следующий, без значения. Список при этом был бы закольцован.